# Why does fscanf(...) != 0 not do the same thing as fscanf(...) == 1?

Tags: c, io, scanf

I have a really simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char c;
    while (fscanf(f, "%c", &c) == 1) {
        printf("char: %c\n", c);
    }
}
```

which works perfectly fine, reading one character at a time from the file. But if I change the condition on the while loop to `while (fscanf(f, "%c", &c) != 0)`, the program appears to get stuck in an infinite loop of printing some whitespace character. I looked at the assembly, and they're identical except for a single instruction:

`== 1 version`

```
...
  40068a:       be 5d 07 40 00          mov    $0x40075d,%esi
  40068f:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400692:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400697:       e8 94 fe ff ff          callq  400530 <__isoc99_fscanf@plt>
  40069c:       83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  40069f:       74 c9                   je     40066a <main+0x24>
  4006a1:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4006a6:       c9                      leaveq 
  4006a7:       c3                      retq   
  4006a8:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4006af:       00
```

`!= 0 version`

```
  40068a:       be 5d 07 40 00          mov    $0x40075d,%esi
  40068f:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400692:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400697:       e8 94 fe ff ff          callq  400530 <__isoc99_fscanf@plt>
  40069c:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  40069e:       75 ca                   jne    40066a <main+0x24>
  4006a0:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4006a5:       c9                      leaveq 
  4006a6:       c3                      retq   
  4006a7:       66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

And the only difference is a `test` versus `cmp`. This is as far as my knowledge of reading assembly goes, and I don't see a difference. So what causes the difference in behavior?

Comment: perhaps `fscanf` might also return `EOF` (which could be negative)

Comment: Comparing against a specific nonzero value *ought* to be different than comparing against zero.

Comment: Think about it, what are the possible return values of `fscanf()`? What happens in case of `==1` and what in the case of `!=0` at all the possible return values you can expect.

Comment: @IronMan `EOF` ***must*** be negative, per [**7.21 Input/output <stdio.h>** paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p3): "... `EOF`

which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value ..."

Comment: Good point, thanks @AndrewHenle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fscanf` returns `EOF` define constant if the end of file is reached before read attempt (i.e. last successful fscanf in this case), not zero. Usually `EOF` equals to `-1`, that's why the second version turns into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Logically the two are not equivalent.

The first condition is true only when fscanf returns 1, which means 1 pattern was matched.

The second condition is true if fscanf returns any value other than 0.  So a return value of 2 for example would stay in the loop.  That won't be returned because there is only one pattern, but what could be returned is -1, and it will be returned when you hit eof.  At that point any future calls will continue to return -1, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: `EOF` is not necessarily −1, although it is negative. And is returned for any input failure (such as a broken pipe), not just end-of-file.